Issue with webapp or Azure?: This region has quota of 0 PremiumV2 cores for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU
I am trying to deploy a flask web app to azure. This app will run the whisperx model on the service. I am trying to use the P1V3 tier to deploy this app but I am receiving this error when changing the plan: *Scale operation failed:
This region has quota of 0 PremiumV3 cores for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.

and then this error when running
az webapp up -n deploymentname:
This region has quota of 0 PremiumV2 cores for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.
I am trying to deploy to the UK servers. Is this a capacity issue? In this case, which location should I switch to? Or is it an issue with my actual webapp? The structure of my directory is app.py, home.py, requirements.txt and then a templates folder with my html files. I would appreciate any advice.
Tried switching locations and plans which should have resulted in a premium core being available.

Are you using a free trial subscription? @not in use

yes i am @Jahnavi

In free trial subscriptions, the quota for using premium tier app service plans is restricted as it needs high quota of instances. Only basic, free tiers or P0V3 will work without any issues. @not in use

I also have a free trial and tried to upgrade my plan to P1V3 and the warning shown as here. @not in use

Ah that's annoying, thank you @Jahnavi. Do you think these will be enough for running this? https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX

Updated below. Please check. @not in use

Legend, thank you very much @Jahnavi very useful stuff. This is definitely going to keep me busy today


This region has quota of 0 PremiumV3 cores for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.

Need to check below:
As you mentioned the free trial subscription is being used in your environment, Premium V3 cores upgrade for app service plan is not possible. Instead try using Basic, Free or P0V3 tiers to avoid conflicts.
In my free trial account, I tried to upgrade my service plan to achieve your requirement which resulted the same conflict as you.

And also check the subscription usage and quotas by visiting your relevant subscription as shown below.

Refer Github for more relevant information.
Sometimes the issue occurs with the region as well. Changing the region to the other than existed one will create a successful deployment.

Do you think these will be enough for running this?

Yes, the provided Github is enough for deploying and running the whisperx model.
Here I have used the same az webapp up command in my paid subscription and was working without any quota issues as shown below.

If you don't have one, use below workaround for web app deployment in a free trial subscription.
Upload whisperX model file to Azure CLI or clone all the files from GitHub with github clone <URL>
1.
Manage Files >> Upload >> upload it from the local after downloading the files from GitHub repo.

2.
Or Go to Azure CLI and provide github clone <URL> command.

Once it is uploaded, now use az webapp deploy CLI command to deploy it into the P0V3 app service plan which is already created through Portal.
az webapp deploy --resource-group "Jahnavi" --name "apsjahn" --src-path "/home/xxx/whisperX-main.zip"




